# Sum arrays within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code (taken **verbatim** from the second example in Chap 2 of Data Visualization with Python on JavaScript by Kyran Dale)

```
student_data = [
  {'name': 'Bob',   'id':0, 'scores':[68, 75, 56, 81]},
  {'name': 'Alice', 'id':1, 'scores':[75, 90, 64, 88]},
  {'name': 'Carol', 'id':2, 'scores':[59, 74, 71, 68]},
  {'name': 'Dan',   'id':3, 'scores':[64, 58, 53, 62]},
]

def  process_student_data(sdata, pass_threshold = 60, merit_threshold = 75):
    av = sum(sdata['scores'])/float(len(sdata['scores'])) # <<== PROBLEM LINE!!

    sdata ['average'] = av

    if av > merit_threshold:
        sdata['assessment'] = 'Passed with merit'
    elif av > pass_threshold:
        sdata['assessment'] = 'Passed'
    else:
        sdata['assessment'] = 'Failed'

    print("%s's (id: %d) final assessment is: %s" %(sdata['name'], sdata['id'], sdata['assessment'].upper()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_student_data(student_data)
```

but on running "python do_student_data.py" (my name for the file) the error I'm getting is:

```
  File "do_student_data.py", line 9, in process_student_data
    print(sdata['scores'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I've programmed before (C, Delphi, Java) and I can see what the interpreter is saying, but I just can't figure out how to fix it. I have Googled various things like "Python sum array in list" and similar, but no  joy.

I would be grateful for:

1. a code fix and more importantly
2. a thorough explanation of the ins and outs of where this code is wrong

Comment: Is that a recent book? The code has a few Python 2 things going on.

Comment: 2016 - he says in the into that he's using Python 3 and that Scrapy is the only library left that doesn't deal well with it - which may have changed in the meantime!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input data is not a single `dict`, but a `list` of `dict`s. So you will have to iterate it and do the action for each `dict` individually:

```
def  process_student_data(student_data, pass_threshold = 60, merit_threshold = 75):
    for sdata in student_data:  # iterate the list!
        # float(...) cast not strictly necessary in Python3
        av = sum(sdata['scores'])/float(len(sdata['scores'])) 
        # ...

>>> process_student_data(student_data)
Bob's (id: 0) final assessment is: PASSED
Alice's (id: 1) final assessment is: PASSED WITH MERIT
Carol's (id: 2) final assessment is: PASSED
Dan's (id: 3) final assessment is: FAILED
```

Alternatively, you can leave your function as it is and call it in a loop:

```
for sdata in student_data:
    process_student_data(sdata)
```

Comment: You can get rid of that `float` cast, the OP's using Python 3.

Comment: @PM2Ring True, but not harmful either. Just keep it as close to the OP's code as possible to focus on the main point :)

Comment: Your answers don't appear to work - see my edit to my question. TIA.

Comment: You have to call the function in the loop with sdata, not student_data.

Comment: My apologies - I'm giving you a correct answer and a +1. The first answer was obvious enough on reflection (but don't forget I'm more or less a complete novice in Python + indentation still doing my head in - just figured out how to get editor to input spaces rather than tabs!!! :-) ) and as for the second, well, I should have actually used the code you gave me rather than rushing to condemn (I used "process_student_data(student_data)" rather than "process_student_data(sdata)"). "Doh <slaps forehead...>" - a Homer Simpson moment I'm afraid! Thanks again!

Comment: I'll edit your answer to explicitly state about the indentation for the first part - it's not altogether obvious when one is a novice! :-)